# how to change rails to development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In the documentation of rails (3.2.3) it says

> In development mode (which is what you’re working in by default), Rails reloads your application with every browser request, so there’s no need to stop and restart the web server.

But clearly my app loads in production mode out of the box.(I can type Rails.env and see it).

Why?

I then go to environment.rb and add

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "development"
```

and still it is in production. 
Any idea?

Edit : Here you go

```
#Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
MyAppName::Application.initialize!

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "development"
```

Comment: Please add your config/environment.rb code here.

Comment: did. added herer -# instead of # because of stackoverflow formattings

Comment: How are you starting your app?

Comment: If you want ENV["RAILS_ENV"] to have effect, set it at the top of the file, before the require.

Comment: When you are on the UNIX command line, what do you get when you type my next comment?

Comment: @andrew - Thanks that was the answer. the command line that ruby ran included prod parameter. my bad.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Though this is not a solution try to start the Rails server this way:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails s
```

What do you see if put `<%= Rails.env %>` somewhere in you layout file?

Answer (score 27):

Possible solution for your situation could be:

```
rails server -e development
```

Comment: Thanks. command is not valid =in my version of rails. plus I want to put it in development mode.

Comment: sorry. I am very new in rails. Should it work through regular windowws cmd line? http://i.imgur.com/BCKAs.png

Comment: @perry You need to run the command in your Rails project's directory.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Phusion Passenger, then add the following to your virtual host configuration file:

```
   RailsEnv development
```

In other words, on my system, you would vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/[name of app] so that it looks like the following:

```
   <VirtualHost *>
   ServerName example.com
   DocumentRoot /home/yourname/htdocs/example.com/public
   RailsEnv development
   </VirtualHost>
```

You would then need to restart the web server:

```
   sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Credit goes to: http://my.opera.com/williamn/blog/2009/03/03/how-to-make-phusion-passenger-run-in-development-mode